# TSQL Trigger Not Saving Variables and/or not Executing Properly

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I've having trouble getting a TSQL trigger to even work correctly. I've run it through the debugger and it's not setting *any* of the variables according to SQL Server Management Studio. The damnedest thing is that the trigger itself is executing correctly and there are no errors when it is executed (just says 'execution successful').

The code is as follows (it's a work in progress.... just getting my self familiar):

```
USE TestDb

IF EXISTS (SELECT name FROM sysobjects
      WHERE name = 'OfficeSalesQuotaUpdate' AND type = 'TR')
   DROP TRIGGER OfficeSalesQuotaUpdate
GO

CREATE TRIGGER OfficeSalesQuotaUpdate
ON SalesReps
AFTER UPDATE, DELETE, INSERT 
AS
    DECLARE @sales_difference int,  @quota_difference int
    DECLARE @sales_original int,    @quota_original int
    DECLARE @sales_new int,         @quota_new int

    DECLARE @officeid int
    DECLARE @salesrepid int

    --UPDATE(Sales) returns true for INSERT and UPDATE.
    --Not for DELETE though.    

    IF ((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM inserted) = 0)
        SET @salesrepid = (SELECT SalesRep FROM deleted)
    ELSE    
        SET @salesrepid = (SELECT SalesRep FROM inserted)   

    --If you address the @salesrepid variable, it does not work. Doesn't even 
    --print out the 'this should work line.
    PRINT 'This should work...' --+ convert(char(30), @salesrepid)

    IF (@salesrepid = NULL)
        PRINT 'SalesRepId is null'
    ELSE
        PRINT 'SalesRepId is not null'

    PRINT convert(char(50), @salesrepid)


    SET @officeid = (SELECT RepOffice 
                       FROM SalesReps 
                      WHERE SalesRep = @salesrepid)

    SELECT @sales_original =    (SELECT Sales FROM deleted)
    SELECT @sales_new =         (SELECT Sales FROM inserted)

    --Sales can not be null, so we'll remove this later.
    --Use this as a template for quota though, since that can be null.
    IF (@sales_new = null) 
    BEGIN
        SET @sales_new = 0
    END

    IF (@sales_original = 0)
    BEGIN
        SET @sales_original = 0
    END

    SET @sales_difference = @sales_new - @sales_original

    UPDATE Offices
    SET Sales = Sales + @sales_difference
    WHERE Offices.Office = @officeid
GO
```

So, any tips? I've completely stumped on this one.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Whatever else might be wrong here, your trigger isn't written well to cope with multi row operations - the inserted and deleted pseudo tables can contain multiple rows.

Comment: That's fine, it's just for class. But on the other hand, how do you know how to have both rows from each of the virtual 'inserted' and 'updated' tables when there is more than one row?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your main problem seems to be that there is a difference between `@foo = NULL` and `@foo IS NULL`:

```
declare @i int
set @i = null -- redundant, but explicit

if @i = null print 'equals'
if @i is null print 'is'
```

The 'This should work' PRINT statement doesn't work because concatenating a NULL with a string gives a NULL, and `PRINT NULL` doesn't print anything.

As for actually setting the value of @salerepid, it seems most likely that the inserted and/or deleted table is in fact empty. What statements are you using to test the trigger? And have you printed out the COUNT(*) value?

You should also consider (if you haven't already) what happens if someone changes more than one row at once. Your current code assumes that only one row is changed at a time, which may be a reasonable assumption in your environment, but it can easily break if someone bulk loads data or does other 'batch processing'.

Finally, you should always mention your MSSQL version and edition; it can be relevant for some syntax questions.

Answer (score 2):

You should replace the body of the trigger with something like this:

```
;WITH Totals AS (
     SELECT RepOffice,SUM(Sales) as Sales FROM inserted GROUP BY RepOffice
     UNION ALL
     SELECT RepOffice,-SUM(Sales) FROM deleted GROUP BY RepOffice
), SalesDelta AS (
     SELECT RepOffice,SUM(Sales) as Delta FROM Totals GROUP BY RepOffice
)
UPDATE o
SET Sales = Sales + sd.Delta
FROM
    Offices o
        inner join
    SalesDelta sd
        on
             o.Office = sd.RepOffice
```

This will adequately cope with multiple rows in inserted and deleted. I'm assuming SalesRep is the primary key of the SalesReps table.

---

Updated above, to cope with UPDATE changing the RepOffice of a particular Sales Rep (which the original doesn't, presumable, get correct either)

Comment: Where is delta being selected from?

Comment: @Nitrodist - it's a new column being introduced in the CTEs before the update statement - it's the sum of all the sales values in the inserted table (for a particular RepOffice), minus the sum of all sales values in the deleted table (for the same RepOffice)

Comment: So shouldn't it be `FROM Totals`? in that statement?

Comment: @Nitrodist - yes, you're right, sorry. There should be a `FROM Totals` in the second CTE. I've updated it. (It's always difficult to write SQL correctly without actual tables + sample data to work from)

Answer (score 0):

Just a suggestion...have you tried putting BEGIN and END to encapsulate the 'AS' part of your trigger?

Comment: That's not required for a `TRIGGER` as the `GO` signifies the end of the `TRIGGER`.